# ITargetLocator's ParentFrame() throws "Invalid Command Method" exception

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS and selenium WebDriver, all recently downloaded using NuGet so should be the latest version. All I have is a page that contains an iframe element and this code (after navigating to the page):

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")));
driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
```

The last line throws a "Invalid Command Method" exception. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Will `DefaultContent` switch to the frame you want? Or does it have to be `ParentFrame`?

Comment: @mrfreester I'd like it to switch back to the parent frame since this is part of a generic function and I want to switch it back to wherever it originally was, which won't necessarily be the default content.

Comment: What if you did `window = driver.CurrentWindowHandle` before you switch to the frame, and then switch back after with `driver.SwitchTo().Window(window)`? Although, it would still be nice to understand why `ParentFrame` isn't working...

Comment: @mrfreester The `CurrentWindowHandle` property is the same regardless of the frame. I think it only changes for popups and actual windows but not frames.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my brain is stuck on getting back to the main window instead of the direct parent. Does `ParentFrame` work with other drivers, or is this just an issue with `phantomjs`? looks like this might be a [known current issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13647) with the `phantomjs` driver.

Comment: I take that back... it looks like that was supposedly fixed...

Comment: @mrfreester Have you been able to reproduce this? Wonder if I'm the only one having this issue.